# Using instafeed.js in Magento via static block

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, javascript, cms, cms-block

I tried using instafeed.js from http://instafeedjs.com/ to show an instagram feed using a particular hashtag right before the footer on my homepage.

I added the file instafeed.min.js to my default/theme/js

I created a static block called instafeed with the content

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'my client ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

Then to the homepage layout xml I added

```
<block type="cms/block" name="instagram" after="previous block's name">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>instafeed</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Is this the correct way to integrate?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: How does the file `instafeed.min.js` get included on the page?

Comment: @Marius This is how it is set up

Comment: @clockworkgeek I'm sorry I forgot to mentio, I added to the layout xml <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>instafeed.min.js</name></action>

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm with the same problem here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to integrate?

Yes.

To clarify, you are using the right method because the script is only used on one page.  If you wanted it to be included with every page then you could use the setting *System > Configuration > Design > Footer > Miscellaneous HTML* instead.

Comment: The problem is, its not working! I know it's not possible to debug from here. I'll just go over it all again myself, see if I've got anything wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it's not working that changes things.  View the source of the page and check all appropriate parts are being output.  Do not assume it's OK, prove it.  The `instafeed.min.js` file and your block's content should be visible in the source.

Comment: You were right, it was looking for instafeed.min.js in the base folder not the theme folder, I copied that over. I can see the block's contents before the footer too, but the feed still does not show up..

Comment: I cracked it! I was forgetting the <div>. I added that to the page and it works now. Thank you for your help!